# Data array not working properly?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Having a few issues with this code, I am trying to get the full list of info from my database where the user2 is equal to the logged in user and the status is '1'. For example, here is my database:

```
user1: 76, 11, 11, 87
user2: 11, 22, 15, 11
status: 1, 1, 1, 1
```

Here is my php code:

```
<?
$user_id = $_SESSION['userid'];

$data = mysql_query("
    SELECT 
        user1 
    FROM 
        friend_requests 
    WHERE 
        user2 = '$user_id' 
    AND 
        status = '1'
") or die(mysql_error());  

$friend_list = mysql_fetch_array( $data );
foreach($friend_list as $friend_list) {
    echo $friend_list, '<br>';
}
?>
```

This code is only displaying the number "76" because it's the first number that is equal to the selection in the database (logged in as '11'). However the number "87" which is the same case is not showing? Plus it will not let me display the "status" either? Any ideas how to get this working? I am a novice in this kind of thing. Thanks!

P.S I know MySQL is outdated but nothing I can do about that at the moment.

Comment: MySQL ain't outdated. PHP's mysql_ API is deprecated.

Comment: First: If you want to display more fields you need to add them to your query. `Select user1, user2, status FROM ...`. Second: If you want to fetch more than one data row you need to execute `mysql_fetch_array` more than once. The best way to do it is to use a while-loop like @iCode4U or @MarkS did it in their answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?
    $user_id = $_SESSION['userid'];

    $data = mysql_query("
        SELECT 
            user1,status
        FROM 
            friend_requests 
        WHERE 
            user2 = '$user_id' 
        AND 
            status = '1'
    ") or die(mysql_error());  

    while($friend_list = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))//added this
    {

        echo $friend_list[¨user1¨].$friend_list[¨status¨].'<br>';

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: That works perfectly, although all of the results are showing twice?

Comment: try now without the foreach

Answer (score 0):

In your code you fetch only one row of data. That is because `mysql_fetch_array` fetch only one "row" from resultset:

```
$friend_list = mysql_fetch_array( $data );
```

That is why your foreach gets only 1 row, and dispplays it.
If you want to get full list fetch data like this:

```
while($friend_list = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
    echo $friend_list, '<br>';
}
```

In this case loop will fetch rows untin there will be data to fetch.